# Magento: Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested object

Tags: magento, xampp, localhost

I am trying to install magento on my local machine but it will show access forbidden error

I have attach screen shot below

[image]

I am using ubantu.

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: Updating system-wide file permissions after unzipping/extracting the .zip and make sure you're in the root directory of your Magento instance. Then run these commands

` find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644
    find ./ -type d | xargs chmod 755
    chmod -Rf 777 var
    chmod -Rf 777 media`

Comment: You can accept the answer if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment above it's an easy fix via SSH. Make sure you're in the root directory of your Magento installation, and then execute the following commands:

```
find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644
find ./ -type d | xargs chmod 755
chmod -Rf 777 var
chmod -Rf 777 media
```

Clear your browser cache and reload the URL of your Magento instance. At this point you should be able to continue with the browser-based installation process and begin setting up your store.

Comment: yes now I have problem with setting base url:   showing this error      The URL "http://localhost/magento/" is not accessible.
        Unable to read response, or response is empty

Comment: For that tick the checkbox 'Skip Base URL Validation' before the next step and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Apply following permissions :

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \; 
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; 
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; 
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
chmod 700 includes
chmod 600 includes/config.php
```